# Understanding the specific interchange of sum and integral

Tags: analysis, alternative-proof

Why is it allowed to write this way,
$$\int_{0}^{m} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi k}\frac{\sin(2\pi k t)}{t^{s+1}}\,\mathrm{d}t=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi k}\int_{0}^{m} \frac{\sin(2\pi k t)}{t^{s+1}} \,\mathrm{d}t?$$
The author wrote that it follows from Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, but I don't really see how it satisfies the theorem.

**Note**: it is proven that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sin(k\theta)}{k}$$
is uniformly bounded for all $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What are the restrictions on $s$?

Comment: @Dominik The restriction is $-1<\Re s<0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the sequence of functions
$$f_n(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi t^{s + 1}}\sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{\sin(2\pi kt)}{k}.$$

As you've said, the sum $\sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{\sin(2\pi kt)}{k}$ is uniformly bounded by a constant $M$. This yields $|f_n(t)| \le  \frac{M}{2\pi} |t|^{-(\Re(s)+1)}$, which gives an integrable upper bound for $f_n$. Now the dominated convergence theorem yields the assertion.

**Edit:** More precisely, write $g_k(t) = \frac{\sin(2\pi k t)}{2\pi k t^{s + 1}}$. Since $\frac{M}{2\pi} |t|^{-(\Re(s)+1)}$ is an integrable function on the interval $[0, m]$, the dominated convergence theorem yields
$$\begin{align*}
\int \limits_0^m \sum \limits_{k = 1}^\infty g_k(t) dt
&= \int\limits_0^m \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n g_n(t) dt 
= \int\limits_0^m \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(t) dt
= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int\limits_0^m f_n(t) dt\\
&= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^m \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n g_k(t) dt
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I have thought the similar way, but how exactly does this theorem explain about interchanging the integral and sum? This is where I have been stuck. Or is this because of the integral addition?

Comment: I've made my answer more detailed.